# How to iterate over an object and get the correct keys with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following object:

```
{
  "1":{
    "ProductType":"car",
    "ProductId":"1",
    "Brand":"Tesla",
  },
  "2":{
    "ProductType":"car",
    "ProductId":"2",
    "Brand":"Ferrari",
  }
  etc...
}
```

Now i need to create a loop that iterates through the object, and i need the product id and the brand and display those. How do i do that?

I have looked at dozens of stack overflow questions and i don't find any that are about exactly my use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using jQuery, you're looking for `jQuery.each()`.

```js
var data = {
  "1":{
    "ProductType":"car",
    "ProductId":"1",
    "Brand":"Tesla",
  },
  "2":{
    "ProductType":"car",
    "ProductId":"2",
    "Brand":"Ferrari",
  }
}

$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
  console.log(i+': '+obj.ProductType+' | '+obj.ProductId+' | '+obj.Brand);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!